# Could=might be able to?

Tags: modal-verbs

Can you please give me an example where ***could*** might be used as meaning ***might be able to***?

Comment: I _could_ get there by four o'clock as long as the roads aren't too busy.

Comment: @KateBunting,'could' in your example really means 'might be able to' or just 'might'. Can we substitute 'might' there?

Comment: Kate gave you an answer to your question...

Comment: @KateBunting,would you stress the 'could' a bit if you were to use that sentence in speech?

Comment: Yes, I probably would.

Answer (score 1):

It's normally used that way when we want to state some conditions when the thing would be possible.

> I could afford a new Playstation, if I get some overtime this month.